# how to make logout button properly work in HTML

Tags: php

I have designed a website and there is a logout option in sub menu.The code is in HTML and is here:-

```
<p><a href="adminlogin.php" target="self">logout</a></p>
```

Now this successfully brings me back to the adminlogin.php page but after that whenever I press the back button present at the top of web browser I go to that page again where I was before pressing logout button. But this should not happen if I have pressed the logout button then there should be no way to go back to that page unless I login again

Comment: If you are using sessions, you need to destroy your session on logout and check for sessions on every authenticated page.

Comment: How are you verifying that the user is logged in? Using a client cookie or a server session? Either way, your walled off log-in area is not validating the session, hence giving the appearance that the user is still logged in. This is a rather broad question because we do not know how your user sessions are managed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is better to logout in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615057/what-is-better-to-logout-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)

Answer (score 2):

> **To avoid browser back button after logout:**

---

> You Have To Add the top of each page, to check if the user is logged
>   in. If not, they should be redirected to a login page:

**Example:**

```
<?php 
      if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['useremail'])){

       header("Location: login.php");  // redirect to login page or index page if email and username is not set in session
  } 

?>
```

> Now on Logout page, Simply unset the `username` and `useremail`
>   session variable, and destroy the session or ( Cookies). what you set.

**Example:**

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {  
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION["username"]);
    unset($_SESSION["useremail"]);

    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
    }
 ?>
```

---

---

> **Working CODE For All Pages After User Login:**  `Home.php` `about.php` `contact.php` etc..

**Example:**

```
<?php 
// After User Login and come to home page.

 require 'database_conn.php'; // Connection
 session_start();    // Session start
?>


<?php

// If User is Not Login Then Redirect to `index` Page Automatically

//if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['useremail']))

if(!isset($_SESSION['useremail'])){

    header("Location: index.php");
    // Redirect to index page if email is not set in session

}
?>
```

> **Working CODE For to Logout User:**  `Logout.php`

**Example:**

```
<?php 
// After User Click On Logout page.
 require 'database_conn.php'; // Connection
 session_start();    // Session start
?>


 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {  

    if(isset($_SESSION['useremail'])){

     unset($_SESSION["useremail"]);
     session_destroy();
     session_unset();    
     header('Location: index.php');

      }
    }
 ?>
```

---

---

---

> **Simple Logout Button**

```
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

> **logout.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) { 

session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

> **Or If Cookie Set Then**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {    
    unset($_COOKIE['access_token']);
    header('Location: login.php');    
    exit;

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need session to do this.
So basically when you logged in you need to set session variable like

```
$_SESSION['loged_in']=1; // set session with desired name
```

And on logging out you need to destroy this session value

```
 unset($_SESSION["loged_in"]); // unset specific session
```

or

```
session_destroy();  // destroy al
```

And most important part you need to check for this session value on each page where you don't want user       to go with out log in. like

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['loged_in']) && !empty($_SESSION['loged_in'])) {
     redirect('login.php'); // redirect to log in page 
}
```